# Prevent body scrolling in Chrome on Android doens't work and generated error message

Tags: android, google-chrome, scroll

I'm trying to prevent scrolling of the body content when reaching the end of the scrollable content in a fixed div.

It was working really well in iOS, and still is, and well enough in Chrome on Android. 
But when we did some testing a few days ago, suddenly it worked really bad in Chrome. It might be related to the release of Chrome 36 on the 14 of august.

When reaching the bottom of the fixed div, and I'll continue to "scroll" without stopping or lifting my finger, the body starts to scroll, even though it should be prevented by my script, and generated the following error message:

> Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for
>   example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

Is there anyway around this? Or some other trick I can use?

The following code is used:

```
var scrolling = false,
ts = null;

$('body').on('touchstart.scrollable', '.a', function(e) {
  // Only execute the below code once at a time
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
      e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
    } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
      e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
    }
    scrolling = false;
  }
  ts = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
});

$('body').on('touchmove.scrollable', '.a', function(e) {
  //If there is no scrollabe content we disable default event
  var te = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY,
      direction = ts > te ? 'down' : 'up';


  $container = $('.a');
  $content = $('.b');

  if ($content.height() <= $container.height()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Default prevented');
  } else if ($container.scrollTop() <= 1 && direction == 'up') {
      e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Default prevented');
  } else if ($container.scrollTop() > 0 && ($container.scrollTop() + $container.height() >= $content.height() - 1) && direction == 'down') {
      e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Default prevented');
  }

  /* Keep from bubbling */
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Please see the following example for complete source and to test:

[Link to JSBin](http://jsbin.com/riwajopuvuzo/1/edit) (They seems to expire after 24 hours) Please press File -> Clone if that has happend, and then view in fullscreen)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue recently on android. very frustrating, especially as the debug affects what happens.

In the end, I ended up putting a transparent div over the scrollable div and writing my own touch handlers on it that passed down the delta between the touchstart and touchmove event Y position to the scrollTop() function of the scrollable div (using jquery). This allowed me complete control of the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had it all worked out, then it stopped working again.
I added a wrapper around the menu with overflow-y: scroll and 10000px height. 
Since the scroll bubbles I assumed it was gonna bubble to my wrapper and catch the scrolling there. But no, it goes straight to body and scrolls it. Even though it has static height to reflect the screen height and overflow: hidden!important.

It **was however working** when I had the wrapper selected in the DOM tree while debugging in Chrome. I no longer receive the error message when it's selected either.

It also works if you first scroll fast, let go, and let the scroll bubble to the body and continue scrolling until it stops by it self. Next time I scroll the prevent-method works and I don't receive the error message

I have no idea what the fudge is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Calling `preventDefault` on `touchmove` while you are scrolling is not working in Chrome. To prevent performance issues, you cannot interrupt a scroll.

Try to call `preventDefault()` from `touchstart` and everything should be ok.

Comment: But I don't want to cancel the scroll before I reached the end. So that won't work.

Comment: I just get: Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event